# QTreeView showing only parent items

Tags: c++, qt

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(this);

const QModelIndex parent_index = model->index(0,0);
model->insertRow(0,parent_index);
model->insertColumn(0,parent_index);
model->setData(model->index(0,0,parent_index),QStringLiteral("Parent Item"));

const QModelIndex child_index = model->index(0,0,parent_index);
model->insertRow(0,child_index);
model->insertColumn(0,child_index);
model->setData(model->index(0,0,child_index),QStringLiteral("Child Item"));

const QModelIndex grand_child_index = model->index(0,0, child_index);
model->insertRow(0,grand_child_index);
model->insertColumn(0,grand_child_index);
model->setData(model->index(0,0,grand_child_index),QStringLiteral("Grand Child Item"));

ui->treeview->setModel(model);
```

It showing only "Parent Item". It is not now showing "Child Item" or "Grand Child Item". What I am doing wrong ? I want to display hierarchy of items in QTreeView.

*My Expectation*

```
Parent Item
    Child Item
        Grand Child Item
```

**What I got**

```
Parent Item
```

Comment: add `ui->treeview->expandAll();` after `ui->treeview->setModel(model);`

Comment: In my test it works but by default the items are not expanded so you only see the top item. So you have to expand it manually by clicking on the item or programmatically as I point out in my previous comment